# Javascript post to check username availability not working

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Im trying to check if the register username's available but everytime the clientside returns that the username its available.

This is my clientside code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#register_username").blur(function(){
    var user = $("#register_username").val();
    $.post("register",
    {
        username: user
    },
    function(data, status){
        if(data == '1')
        {
            alert('Good, username its available!');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Snap!You cant use this username :(!');
        }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the serverside code:

```
if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 0)
{
    $usr = $_POST['username'];
    if($usr == 'test')
        echo '1';
    else
        echo '2';
}
```

PHP Version: 5.5

Comment: on the server side you should use a query to check if the username exists or not

Comment: How's your data goes the second php code if you didn't give url in post.

Comment: @mplungjan, i still have the same problem.

Comment: @ anant kumar singh, it works, my urls are htaccess modified. If i try to echo the posted value it will work so thats not my problem!

Comment: @Abhishek Ghosh, it should work with this simple check too.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, i guess if the input field has value "test" it would say "you cannot use this username"?

in your code if input is "test" `($usr == "test" - that comes from input)` you `echo 1`, and in your code 1 means **username** is **available**? So shouldn't it be backwards?

Does it say "username is available" with every input?

Comment: Yes, username its available no matter what the input contains.

Comment: well, i recreated this for testing and it worked perfectly..

the only thing i changed was
`if(data == '2')`
to get the right alert. I suggest you to echo out the `$_POST['username']`

Comment: i've did the same thing but it still returns the same alert.

Comment: did you tried to echo out the `$_POST['username']` ?